# Discord.js Bot Send Message After 10 Messages in Channel

Tags: javascript, bots, discord, discord.js

Hey I was wondering if it was possible to have a bot send a message after 10 messages within a channel. Like can you record the amount of messages in the channel, and then when that reaches a specific amount, such as 10 more messages, then output a message to the channel?

Comment: you could use a counter that increases on each message and resets after you send a message. Show your code. What issue are you facing ?

Comment: Message event should help you https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client?scrollTo=e-message

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it easily:

```
let counter = 0;
client.on("message", () => {
    if(++counter === 10){
        message.channel.send("10 messages were sent!");
        counter = 0;
    }
});
```

(`client` is your Discord.js Client instance)